# node.js - if else - string for - res.end()

Tags: javascript, node.js

my index.js ( nick name: 1.js )

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var Memcached = require('memcached');
var memcached = new Memcached('localhost:11211');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '-----------',
    user     : '2',
    password : '----------',
    database : '1'
});

connection.connect();


var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});

    try{
    var o = require('/2.js')
    } catch (err){
    var o = '0'
    }

    if (o == '0'){
        o = 'page not found'
    }else{
         o.makeQuery(connection, function(err, result){
             if(err) return res.end(err);
             o = result
         });
    }

    res.end(o)

}).listen(80);
```

my /2.js

```
exports.makeQuery = function(connection, callback) {

  var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM 1_accounts order by ac_nu asc limit 5';

  connection.query(queryString, function(err,res,fields){
    if (err) {return callback(err)};

    bb = JSON.stringify(res);
    callback(null, bb);
  });
}
```

the error:

```
root@11669:/# node 1.js
_http_outgoing.js:524
    throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer');
    ^

TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:524:11)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/1.js:38:6)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:528:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:88:23)
root@11669:/#
```

the problem is located somewhere towards the end of the index.js (1.js)
right after the "else" statement.

not sure how to correct it.

i do not believe anywhere else there are conflicts.
2.js should be fine as is.

update: 
The error occurred **AFTER** i loaded it on the web

Comment: Perhaps i am unable to send anything to res.end() from under neath the o.makeQuery where i have o set to "result". in other words perhaps i am unable to set a value for "o" at that point.

Comment: You made an async call and then call res.end with an object, hence the error

Comment: is there a way to make a call without asking for a call back or an error report so that i can completely remove .. function(err, result){
             if(err) return res.end(err);

Answer (score 0):

you are using asynchronous function makeQuery in 1.js, so you should pass data to browser after completing the makeQuery function. try this

```
if (o == '0'){
    o = 'page not found';
    res.end(o);
}else{
     o.makeQuery(connection, function(err, result){
         if(err) return res.end(err);
         o = result;
         res.end(o)
     });
}
```